Issues with FadeTransition when used with TreeView
I have a similar problem to that reported here. In my application I present a TreeView of "health" status items for a system with a number of components. The requirement is to flash a "BAD" health component in the tree for a limited time in response to the health becoming "BAD" - ie to bring attention to the issue.
As recommended on other posts, I have used the JavaFX FadeTransition class to accomplish this, however, what I sometimes see is the following:

Neighbouring tree nodes sometimes start to flash as well as the target node. This is exacerbated if the TreeView is scrolled.
When the number of cycles completes, the flashing node could be left in a partly faded state.

Here is the code snippet used:
/**
 * Flash a health tree node using the FadeTransition animation
 *
 * @param item The TreeCell item
 * @param rate Flashing rate per second
 * @param mins Number of mins to flash
 */
private void flash(HealthItem item, int rate, int mins) {
  FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1.0 / rate), this);
  fadeTransition.setFromValue(1.0);
  fadeTransition.setToValue(0.0);
  fadeTransition.setCycleCount(mins * rate * 60);
  fadeTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
  fadeTransition.setOnFinished(event -> {
    item.stopFlash();
  });
  item.setFlash(fadeTransition); // This method will call the fadeTransition.play()
}

I will investigate alternate methods for achieving the goal given my observations with FadeTransition.
Any suggestions welcome?
I have also tried using a similar code but with a TimeLine:
  /**
     * Flash a health tree node using the Timeline animation
     *
     * @param item The TreeCell item
     * @param rate Flashing rate per second
     * @param mins Number of mins to flash
     */
    private void flash(HealthItem item, int rate, int mins) {
      KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1.0 / rate), new KeyValue(this.textFillProperty(), Color.PINK));
      Timeline flasher = new Timeline();
      flasher.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
      flasher.setCycleCount(mins * rate * 60);
      flasher.setAutoReverse(true);
      flasher.setOnFinished(event -> {
        item.stopFlash();
      });
      item.setFlash(flasher); // This method will call the .play() method
    }

This also has the same odd behaviour where adjacent nodes to the flashing node also flash.
Here is the minimal example that exhibits the issue:
package fade;

import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 */
public class FadingTreeCellExample extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // Sample tree structure
    TreeItem<HealthItem> rootItem = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("Root"));
    TreeItem<HealthItem> level1 = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("Level1"));
    TreeItem<HealthItem> level2 = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("Level 2"));
    TreeItem<HealthItem> level3 = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("Level 3"));
    TreeItem<HealthItem> level4 = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("Level 4"));
    TreeItem<HealthItem> level5 = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("Level 5"));

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    boolean addAll = rootItem.getChildren().addAll(level1, level2, level3, level4, level5);
    rootItem.getChildren().forEach(item -> {
      TreeItem<HealthItem> item1 = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("Item 1"));
      TreeItem<HealthItem> item2 = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("FadeMe")); // Node to fade
      TreeItem<HealthItem> item3 = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("Item 3"));
      item.getChildren().addAll(item1, item2, item3);
    });

    rootItem.setExpanded(true);

    TreeView<HealthItem> treeView = new TreeView<>(rootItem);
    treeView.setCellFactory(tv -> new FadingTreeCell());

    StackPane root = new StackPane(treeView);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Fading TreeCell Example");
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public class FadingTreeCell extends TreeCell<HealthItem> {

    private FadeTransition fadeTransition;

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(HealthItem item, boolean empty) {
      super.updateItem(item, empty);

      if (empty || item == null) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
      } else {
        setText(item.getName());

        // Check if this is the correct item to apply the FadeTransition
        if (item.getName().equals("FadeMe")) {
          fade(item, 1, 1);
        } else {
          stopFade();
        }
      }
    }

    /**
     * Flash a health tree node using the FadeTransition animation
     *
     * @param item The TreeCell item
     * @param rate Flashing rate per second
     * @param mins Number of mins to flash
     */
    private void fade(HealthItem item, int rate, int mins) {
      fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1.0 / rate), this);
      fadeTransition.setFromValue(1.0);
      fadeTransition.setToValue(0.0);
      fadeTransition.setCycleCount(mins * rate * 60);
      fadeTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
      fadeTransition.setOnFinished(event -> {
        item.stopFlash();
      });
      item.setFlash(fadeTransition); // This method will call the fadeTransition.play()
    }

    private void stopFade() {
      if (fadeTransition != null) {
        fadeTransition.stop();
        fadeTransition = null;
      }
    }
  }

  private class HealthItem {

    private final String name;
    private FadeTransition flash;

    public HealthItem(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.flash = null;
    }

    private void setFlash(FadeTransition flash) {
      this.flash = flash;
      flash.play();
    }

    private void stopFlash() {
      flash.stop();
    }

    private String getName() {
      return name;
    }

  }
}


When you scroll, and at other times, cells in the tree are reused to display different items. If the cell contains a flashing and reused to display an item for which the flashing is no longer appropriate, you would need to explicitly stop the flashing (and vice-versa). Create and post a [mre]

Using JavaFx 22.0.1 and OpenJDK 22.0.1 on a MacBook Pro running Sonoma 14.6.1

You can post the solution as an answer to your own question

Thanks - I have edited the post and added the answer

Found the answer:
The behavior I observed occurs because JavaFX's TreeView reuses TreeCells to optimize performance, particularly when scrolling or expanding nodes. So sometimes the "fading" transition will get applied where not intended.
The new code I have does the following:
package fade;

import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 */
public class FadingTreeCellExample extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // Sample tree structure
    TreeItem<HealthItem> rootItem = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("Root"));
    TreeItem<HealthItem> level1 = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("Level1"));
    TreeItem<HealthItem> level2 = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("Level 2"));
    TreeItem<HealthItem> level3 = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("Level 3"));
    TreeItem<HealthItem> level4 = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("Level 4"));
    TreeItem<HealthItem> level5 = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("Level 5"));

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    boolean addAll = rootItem.getChildren().addAll(level1, level2, level3, level4, level5);
    rootItem.getChildren().forEach(item -> {
      TreeItem<HealthItem> item1 = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("Item 1"));
      TreeItem<HealthItem> item2 = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("FadeMe")); // Node to fade
      TreeItem<HealthItem> item3 = new TreeItem<>(new HealthItem("Item 3"));
      item.getChildren().addAll(item1, item2, item3);
    });

    rootItem.setExpanded(true);

    TreeView<HealthItem> treeView = new TreeView<>(rootItem);
    treeView.setCellFactory(tv -> new FadingTreeCell());

    StackPane root = new StackPane(treeView);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Fading TreeCell Example");
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public class FadingTreeCell extends TreeCell<HealthItem> {

    private FadeTransition fadeTransition;

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(HealthItem item, boolean empty) {
      super.updateItem(item, empty);

      if (empty || item == null) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
        stopFade();
      } else {
        setText(item.getName());

        // Check if this is the correct item to apply the FadeTransition
        if (item.getName().equals("FadeMe")) {
          fade(1, 1);
        } else {
          stopFade();
        }
      }
    }

    /**
     * Flash a health tree node using the FadeTransition animation
     *
     * @param item The TreeCell item
     * @param rate Flashing rate per second
     * @param mins Number of mins to flash
     */
    private void fade(int rate, int mins) {
      if (fadeTransition == null) {
        fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1.0 / rate), this);
        fadeTransition.setFromValue(1.0);
        fadeTransition.setToValue(0.0);
        fadeTransition.setCycleCount(mins * rate * 60);
        fadeTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
        fadeTransition.setOnFinished(event -> {
          fadeTransition.stop();
        });
      }
      fadeTransition.playFromStart();
    }

    private void stopFade() {
      if (fadeTransition != null) {
        fadeTransition.stop();
        setOpacity(1.0);
        fadeTransition = null;
      }
    }
  }

  private class HealthItem {

    private final String name;

    public HealthItem(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    private String getName() {
      return name;
    }

  }
}

The key is to reset the TreeCell state on every update.
